# Has there been a change in the calculation of Google My Business statistics

Tags: local-seo, google-my-business

My client has about 6,000 locations in their Google My Business account and monitors their visibility with the statistics download from the location overview. Within those very statistics, we have observed a sudden increase in Google Maps Impressions whereas Google Search Impressions (also calls and website clicks) "only" remained stable.

The change occured 09/19 and persists to this day. It happens across all browsers and across a large number of locations. There were no changes to the locations that could explain this selective increase.

Can anyone think of an explanation what could have happened to the GoogleMaps impressions selectively? Is it possible that Google changed the way how they count Maps impressions?

I'll be grateful for any feedback. So far I am stumped.